# Stored procedure parameter where IN (:parameter)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have here a stored procedure which expects two parameters

- `HeadID` integer
- `KdNr` nvarchar(100)

The select in the stored procedure looks like this:

```
select * 
from something 
where HeadID = @HeadID and KdNr in (@KdNr)
```

Now I execute the stored procedure like this

```
exec spTest 21, ('64303')
```

This works but if I add multiple customer numbers (they are integers in the database)

```
exec spTest 21, ('64303', '64304', '64305')
```

I get an error:

> Failed to convert nvarchar to integer.

Can someone please help me / tell me how do I pass multiple integers to a stored procedure like this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause

Comment: `IN` expects a set, you're passing a single string variable. Ideally pass your values as a table valued parameter. If you insist on using a string you need to split it up inside your SP to create a table for `IN`.

Comment: You have to use a string and split the values inside the procedure. Alternatively you can use a table parameter. KdNR IN (@CSV) is same as KdNR = @CSV, so sql server doesn't split it just because you pass some string data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause)

Comment: Instead of using a splitter as suggested in your accepted answer you should look into table valued parameters. They are super easy to use and won't suffer the performance penalties of things like string splitters with loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below function in your procedure.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
(
    @Line nvarchar(MAX),
    @SplitOn nvarchar(5) = ','
)
RETURNS @RtnValue table
(
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Data nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Line IS NULL RETURN;

    DECLARE @split_on_len INT = LEN(@SplitOn);
    DECLARE @start_at INT = 1;
    DECLARE @end_at INT;
    DECLARE @data_len INT;

    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        SET @end_at = CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@Line,@start_at);
        SET @data_len = CASE @end_at WHEN 0 THEN LEN(@Line) ELSE @end_at-@start_at END;
        INSERT INTO @RtnValue (data) VALUES( SUBSTRING(@Line,@start_at,@data_len) );
        IF @end_at = 0 BREAK;
        SET @start_at = @end_at + @split_on_len;
    END;

    RETURN;
END;
```

The above function will split the string into each row.

Now use the above function in your procedure like: `SELECT * FROM something WHERE HeadID = @HeadID AND KdNr IN (SELECT Data FROM dbo.SplitString(@KdNr, ',') WHERE Data <> '')`

Now call your procedure like: `exec spTest 21, '64303,64304,64305'`

Comment: I hope you're sitting down, but there's built-in STRING_SPLIT function since SQL Server 2016 you can mention :)

Comment: @siggemannen: Yes there's built-in STRING_SPLIT function **since** SQL Server 2016. And as I see in the question there no mention of SQL Server version, so i suggest this one. I think you are cleared now.

Comment: Even if they are on an out of date version this splitter is seriously as bad as they get. Even in the "old days" there were several splitters that didn't need a painfully slow loop.

Comment: And a better approach to the problem posted would be to use a table valued parameter instead of passing around delimited strings.